# Enable\Disable button in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to enable or disable button in gridview. Basically each row has this button and on click of this button it redirects on other page with respective row id. I require disable button for some particular user. I will take User name from session.

Comment: And what effort have you put in to attempt this? What have you tried? Have you even tried Google?

Comment: You can create a handler for the RowDataBound event and manipulate the button there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This:

```
protected void Grid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        return;
    }

    Button button = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("btnSubmit");

    int Id = (int) ((DataRowView) e.Row.DataItem)["Id"];

    if(Id == Convert.ToInt32(Session["Id"]))
    {
        button.Enabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        button.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can you [RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event where you will find the button and disable it according to condition

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{               
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Button buttonId= (Button )e.Row.FindControl("buttonId");
        if(Session["Role"] == "admin")
            buttonId.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{

    if (GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text == "NA")
    {
      Button btnVal= (Button)e.Row.FindControl("buttonSubmit");
      btnVal.Enabled = false;

    }
}
}
```

or

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{               
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    Button btnVal= (Button )e.Row.FindControl("buttonSubmit");
    if(Session["Role"] == "admin")
        btnVal.Enabled = false;
}
}
```